# exception handler with siglongjmp interrupting I/O

Tags: c, exception, io, exceptionhandler, setjmp

While working on the homework problem 8.25 in CSAPP, I referred to its solution available at https://dreamanddead.github.io/CSAPP-3e-Solutions/. The provided solution includes the following C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "csapp.h"

sigjmp_buf buf;

void handler(int sig) {
  /* jump */
  siglongjmp(buf, 1);
}

char* tfgets(char* s, int size, FILE* stream) {
  char* result;

  if (!sigsetjmp(buf, 1)) {
    alarm(5);
    if (signal(SIGALRM, handler) == SIG_ERR)
      unix_error("set alarm handler error");
    return fgets(s, size, stream);
  } else {
    /* run out of time */
    return NULL;
  }
}
```

The `tfgets` function is `fgets` with a timeout feature. However, a concern arises regarding the safety of using siglongjmp to jump out of IO operations.

Is it safe to use siglongjmp to interrupt IO operations and exit them abruptly?

I wasn't able to find any document or related questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No!**
It is *not* safe to do `siglongjmp` from this handler. You can corrupt the state of the stream that `fgets` is operating on.

Instead of doing `sigsetjmp/siglongjmp`, have the signal handler set a global (e.g. `volatile int alarm_fired;)`.

Then, if the handler fires, `fgets` should return `NULL` and `errno` should be set to `EINTR`.

You can (safely) check for the return value and `errno` value. You can also check `alarm_fired`.

---

**However ...**

Without the `siglongjmp`, `fgets` will (under linux/glibc, at least) absorb the signal.

And, it's unclear what `errno` *would* be set to (e.g. `EINTR` vs `EAGAIN`) even if it did return immediately.

So, you may have to configure the stream to allow this. Some possibilities:

1. Set the underlying file descriptor to non-blocking
2. Use `cfmakeraw`
3. Use the `FIONREAD` ioctl.
4. Use `select` and/or `poll` on `fileno(stream)`.
5. Dispense with stream I/O and use `read` directly, possibly with some of the other items above.

This *seems* primarily useful to get a timeout from a TTY device (e.g. `stdin`) or a pipe/socket rather than a file. In those cases, to me, `read` seems to be the better bet.

---

*Side note:*
You have a race condition.

You set the signal handler (with `signal`) after doing `alarm`. Under heavy system loading, the signal could fire before you have a chance to set the handler.

Put the `alarm` after the `signal` call.

Comment: Indeed. There's a statement somewhere saying that signal handles should not do anything beyond setting a variable.

Comment: @user207421: The [C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1) is very restrictive about what signal handlers can do.  [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) is a lot more permissive.